# How do I post a file to pastebin or similar service from the command line?

Tags: api

I want to be able to paste from the command line to pastebin (or similar), but it seems that `pastebinit` doesn't work anymore:

```
THIS API HAS BEEN DISABLED. Please use Pastebin's new API. http://pastebin.com/api
```

Comment: Simply use the example code from the new API in a PHP script (under "Creating A New Paste"). I just tried it and it worked right away. Or do you have any specific problems getting that to work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can. Use GitHub gist.

```
curl -X POST \--data-binary '{"files": {"file1.txt": {"content": "Hello, SO"}}}' \https://api.github.com/gists
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Requires authentication",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist"
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

api_key=xxxxxxx-my-dev-API-key-xxxxxxx

curl -d "api_paste_code=$(jq -sRr @uri)" \
     -d "api_dev_key=$api_key" \
     -d 'api_option=paste' 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'

echo  # By default, there's no newline printed by curl
```